# Generate all permutations of a large vector and perform calculations efficently

Tags: r, performance, permutation, large-data, p-value

I have a vector "perm" of length 445, which includes 260 zeros and 185 ones. I need to generate the matrix of all its possible permutations. Then I need to perform a couple of calculations efficiently. I have kind of managed to do this but not completely and not efficiently (I used a loop). I would need help in improving my code, as it would be very instructive.

First, since R does not let me create this huge matrix of permutations, I use the 'ri' package to randomly sample 100,000 permutations.

```
library(ri)    
lalonde <- read.csv('lalonde.csv')
perms <- genperms(lalonde$treat, maxiter=100000)
```

Instead, I would like to be able to generate the full matrix of permutations (or a list of lists, if that works better).

Then, I merge the my original dataset, lalonde, with the permutation dataset.

```
lalonde1 <- data.frame(perms, lalonde)
```

I create an empty vector, where I store the output of the loop that follows

```
diff_vec <- vector(mode='list', length=100000)
```

I create a loop that calculates an absolute conditional difference in means per each permuted vector. I store the results in the empty vector. This is far from efficient and I would very much appreciate if I could get some advice on how to do it better.

```
for (i in 1:100000) {
  diff_vec[i] <- abs((mean(lalonde1[lalonde1[[i]]==1,"re78"])-mean(lalonde1[lalonde1[[i]]==0,"re78"])))
}
```

Finally, for each absolute difference in means, check if it is greater or equal to a value I stored, assigning 1 if it is and 0 otherwise.

```
p_val<-ifelse(diff_vec>=tau_hat, 1, 0)
```

For those who care, this is to calculate an exact p-value in a completely randomised experiment.

Comment: There are approximately 3.3 * 10^133 permutations of your data.   Generating them all going to be a challenge...

Comment: Yeh, I understand it might not be feasible... what about turning the loop into something more efficient?

Comment: I think you don‘t quite understand. The current largest super computer which has 2.4 million cores is able to perform 140*10^15 computations per second at max. Your number of comparisons is already 10^118 times larger. And I guess you don‘t have 2.4 million cores in your computer. So what Limey wants to probably say is: you just won‘t be able to do what you want. It‘s completely irrelevant if you want to do it in a loop or differently. So you have to resuce the site/complexity of your problem extremely.

Comment: Hi @deschen, thank you for your further clarification. I understand that the full permutation matrix is not feasible. I was wondering if, given my current code (and the current size of my matrix of sampled permutations), there were a way to make my loop into an apply() function or something similar. Thanks again